# How to inner join same column

Tags: sql

Sorry for the confusing title, I don't really know how to word it. so what I'm trying to achieve is to define two different column  data into one id.  so  teamID has the team ids, and I'm trying to define both the home ids and away ids on the same inner join, but don't know the proper script

```
SELECT *
FROM fixtures INNER JOIN 
     teams
     ON fixtures.homeTeam = teams.teamID INNER JOIN 
     teams
     ON fixtures.awayTeam = teams.teamID;
```

what I want to achieve is basically teamaway= teamID  and  homeaway = teamID and then TeamID = teamName

Answer (score 3):

You need table aliases:

```
SELECT f.*, th.*, ta.*
FROM fixtures f INNER JOIN 
     teams th
     ON f.homeTeam = th.teamID INNER JOIN 
     teams ta
     ON f.awayTeam = ta.teamID;
```

Note . . . You should select the column that you want explicitly and give them meaningful names.  For instance:

```
SELECT f.*, th.name as home_team, ta.name as away_team
FROM fixtures f INNER JOIN 
     teams th
     ON f.homeTeam = th.teamID INNER JOIN 
     teams ta
     ON f.awayTeam = ta.teamID;
```

Otherwise, you'll have duplicate column names which are a bit hard to understand.

Comment: Hi thank you for you asnwer i also have another question, there's another column in teams called teamName, which has the list of all the names for the teams, (same teamID) and what i want to do is when i homeaway=teamID = teamName, so i get the teamID and from the teamID i get the name, which is displayed onto the table, if that makes sense

Comment: @RESPECTFORYOUISRESEPCTFORJESUS . . . Select the columns you want from `th` and `ta`.  It is that simple.

Comment: would this  be in a  different SQL  statement

Comment: @RESPECTFORYOUISRESEPCTFORJESUS . . . As I understand your comment, the second query answers the question.  If it does not, then I don't understand what you want and you should ask a *new* question,.